# Why does my DNS MX query return an SOA record?

Tags: powershell, dns

I am using PowerShell to get an array of MX records.  I am wondering why the following command would return SOA records as I have specified MX for the type parameter. Furthermore, will an SOA record help with email delivery?

```
Resolve-DnsName $SomeDomainName -type MX -Server 8.8.8.8 -DnsOnly -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: I don't think that it would (nor should it). To my knowledge the SOA record has nothing to do with mail delivery. This is a question for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that Google's Public DNS servers (8.8.8.8) went to the authoritative server for your domain and found no MX records. The SOA record shows the server that it asked, and is basically a reference to say "We contacted the server that should have ALL the records for your domain, and they did not have an available record of the type requested (MX)."

If you are an administrator of the domain, you should look at your configuration. I would guess that you have no MX records for your domain available. Perhaps your domain is misspelled?

SOA records indicate authoritative name servers. For example, if I ask 8.8.8.8 for a SRV record for my domain, it returns the SOA record because our authoritative name server does not host any SRV records.

This question does seem to belong in serverfault, as pointed out by Ansgar. Despite the usage of Powershell and the results being perceived as problematic Powershell output, this is standard DNS behavior. `Resolve-DnsName` is returning exactly what it got from the name server you told it to query. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will post in serverfault.  Thanks.